# How do you do a copy and paste in the Type Library Editor in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, typelib, com-hell

Help

I am busy making changes to a type library in a Datasnap project.

How do I copy and paste text with in the type library editor ?

P.s. I am using BDS2006

EDIT 1

Is there a way to chnage the Type Library without using the TLB Editor ?

EDIT 2

Is there any way to do a copy and paste in the 'Attributes' and 'Users' screens of type library editor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the 'Text' tab and switch off the Read Only checkbox. Then you can copy paste into that tab.

Comment: Thanks - this helps. But I still cannot do a Copy & Paste in the Attributes or Users screens

Comment: If you select the top node you can edit the whole tlb. Maybe that way you can also copy/paste attributes